# FromUri in ASP.NET CORE 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

This question is because in my MVC project with **ASP.NET CORE 2.0**, I can not add the `[FromUri] attribute` to my drivers.

I tried using libraries like `System.Web.Http`, but I did not recognize them. Then install these from Nuget `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` "and" `System.AppDomain.NetCoreApp`, which resulted in being able to use `System.Web.Http` but due to ambiguity problems I was not allowed to use it, but if I found that `[FromUri]` existed.

The main question is whether in ASP.NET core 2.0 MVC or WebApi exists `[FromUri]` ?

if it exists, how to use it?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

I think you might be looking for `[FromQuery]`:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#customize-model-binding-behavior-with-attributes

`[FromUri]` is used in Asp.Net WebApi 2, not asp.net core

Comment: See [FromRoute] or [FromQuery].

Answer (score 77):

**TLDR** : You can use **`[FromQuery]`** and **`[FromRoute]`** in place of `[FromUri]`

---

As Mike_G stated in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48195125/5407188) you can use `[FromQuery]` attribute in place of `[FromUri]`. But you might also need to use `[FromRoute]` in certain cases as pointed by [Muhammad Umar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2219414/muhammad-umar) in comments.

[**FromRoute**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromrouteattribute)

This attribute is used when the parameter is passed as the part of the URL string.

Ex: `api/countries/1`

[**FromQuery**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute)

As the name implies, FromQuery parameters has to be passed as query strings.

Ex: `api/countries?id=1`

**References:**

1. [FromRoute - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromrouteattribute)
2. [FromQuery - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute)
3. [FromUri - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-fromuri)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  `FromQuery` is not always appropriate, which is nicely illustrated by the examples.